# oracle SQL error 00913 too many values

Tags: sql, oracle

Thank for the previous answer I was able to solve the problem am now inserting values into my tables. But i have a little problem with the following;

```
CREATE TABLE RENTALAGREEMENT
( RENTAGREE_NUM NUMBER,
MEM_ID NUMBER,
STF_ID NUMBER,
ECAR_ID NUMBER,
ISSUE_DATE DATE,
RETURN_DATE DATE,
ACTUAL_RETURN DATE,
RENTAL_AMOUNT NUMBER,
LATE_RETURN_CHARGE NUMBER, 
CONSTRAINT RENTAGREE_PK PRIMARY KEY (RENTAGREE_NUM),
CONSTRAINT RENTAGREE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (MEM_ID) REFERENCES MEMBER,
CONSTRAINT RENTAGREE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (STF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF,
CONSTRAINT RENTAGREE_FK3 FOREIGN KEY (ECAR_ID) REFERENCES ECAR
)
```

/
 i tried to insert the following values

```
Insert into rentalagreement 
values(001,'1001','201','300',21/04/2013,('dd/mm/yyyy'),22/04/2013, 
      ('dd/mm/yyyy'),22/04/2013,('dd/mm/yyyy'),'80','null')
```

/

but I keep getting the too many values syntax error. Please can anyone help me

Thank you

Comment: Error is clear,number of values and number of columns must match.

Answer (score 7):

Probably you should write

```
to_date('21/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

instead of

```
21/04/2013,('dd/mm/yyyy')
```

So probably this will work:

```
Insert into rentalagreement 
values(001,1001,201,300,to_date('21/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('22/04/2013', 
      'dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('22/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),80,null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Insert into rentalagreement 
values(001,'1001','201','300',to_date('21/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('24/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),to_date('22/04/2013','dd/mm/yyyy'),'80',null)
```